# Must Read/ Favorite Papers in Database and related fields

Tags: database, database-design, data-mining, distributed

Please recommend what you consider to be the most important or just favorite papers in Database Management, Information Systems, Data Mining etc.

Here are couple that I think are important milestones:

1. What Goes Around Comes Around - Michael Stonebraker, Joseph M. Hellerstein
2. [Dynamo: Amazon’s Highly Available Key-value Store  - Giuseppe DeCandia, Deniz Hastorun, Madan et al](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf)
3. [Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data - Fay Chang, Jeffrey Dean et al.](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html)
4. [MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters - Jeffrey Dean and Sanjay Ghemawat](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html)
5. Brewer's conjecture and the feasibility of consistent, available, partition-tolerant web services
6. [Parallel database systems: the future of high performance database systems - Jim Gray](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dewitt/includes/paralleldb/cacm.pdf)
7. A Formal Model of Crash Recovery in a Distributed System - Skeen, D.  Stonebraker, M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm new on stackoverflow, I can't post more than two hyperlinks!! So the version with links is at http://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/ghc0w/please_recommend_must_read_favorite_papers_in/c1no849

The book that zamanbakshi recommends, *Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques*, by Gray and Reuter, is really, really good. I carried it around so much that the cover fell off--and this is a hardcover.  It is somewhat outdated on some topics, of course, but it is a much better read than most later books, such as Weikum and Vossen's *Transactional Information Systems*, which is a good book, but makes my eyes glaze over, I have to admit.

If I recall correctly, the Gray and Reuter text doesn't cover Mohan's repeating histories recovery technique, which is essential. See ARIES/NT: A Recovery Method Based on Write-Ahead Logging for Nested Transactions and ARIES: A Transaction Recovery Method Supporting Fine-Granularity Locking and Partial Rollbacks Using Write-Ahead Logging, at the very least, but most of Mohan's papers are worth reading.

The book *Concurrency control and Recovery in Database Systems* by Bernstein, et al., is out of print, but you can download it from his Microsoft Research page.

There are also a lot of good publications there from David Lomet and the late (or missing) Jim Gray.

Some important papers that aren't in the 2nd edition of the Red Book (the edition I have):

- A critique of ANSI SQL isolation levels (1995) Gray, et al.
- The dangers of replication and a solution (1996) Gray and Helland
- Generalized Isolation Level Definitions (2000) Adya, et al.

A recent paper that I think deserves more attention is Serializable Isolation for Snapshot Databases (2009) by Cahill, Röhm, and Fekete. It's a really simple technique that works surprisingly well. I hope that it gets implemented in some DBMSes. While searching for related stuff, I came across this interesting reading list. It mostly has flash memory-related stuff, but there are some general papers of interest, too, including some recent Stonebraker papers.

I recommend skipping Date's "Third Manifesto" stuff. I was quite disappointed by it. I don't think he has ever done any object-oriented programming. His earlier books and articles on relational DBMSes are good, if a bit repetitive.

A good description of a main-memory DBMS is The Architecture of the Dalí Main-Memory Storage Manager. The non-action-consisent, non-WAL checkpointing blew my mind at first.

Here are a couple about non-consistent distributed data management (for very, very big data):

- BASE: an Acid alternative (2008) Pritchett
- Life beyond Distributed Transactions: an Apostate's Opinion (2007) Helland

Answer (score 8):

1. First and foremost the most important compendium of papers on DBMS theory that you must read is 'Readings in Database Systems 4E' -- Stonebraker (aka 'The Red Book')

   > Every paper in this book is a
   >   milestone; failing which it wouldn't
   >   have made a cut to this book. :-)
2. Stonebraker also has an excellent survey on DBMS architecture 'Architecture of a Database System' : Foundations and Trends in Databases 1:2 (2007)
3. THE BOOK for DBMS writers: 'Transaction Processing: Concepts and Techniques' -- Jim Gray (his seminal work)
4. This could be considered as a one big paper : 'The Relational Model For Database Management V2' -- Codd
5. Foundations for Object/Relational Databases, The Third Manifesto' --- C. J. Date
6. Readings in Object-Oriented Database Systems -- Zdonik
7. Concurrency control and Recovery in Database Systems -- Bernstein

Comment: Thanks! Is the red book just a compilation of papers or does Stonebraker also comment on the papers?

Comment: I love the Jim Gray book.  Though Sql Server centric, I would recommend [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/mcm.asp) reading list.

Comment: @Kunjan: Yes, he does comment on the papers. The list of papers is divided into sections, and before the start of each section there is a commentary on listed papers... In addition, 'Architecture of a Database System' has the list of must-read papers on each sub-field.